Why is tabindex=0 still used in HTML even when a feature flag is false in Ember.js?
I'm working on an Ember.js project where I've implemented a feature flagging system to control certain UI elements based on specific conditions. However, I've encountered a situation where even when the feature flag is set to false, the tabindex attribute with a value of 0 is still being applied to an HTML element.
This is the simplified version of the code I used:
{{#if shouldShowElement}}
  {{#if isFeatureFlagEnabled}}
    <div class="element" tabindex="0">
      Element content
    </div>
  {{else}}
    <div class="element">
      Element content
    </div>
  {{/if}}
{{/if}}


In this scenario, when isFeatureFlagEnabled is false, I expect the tabindex attribute not to be present in the rendered HTML. However, it still appears.
I've verified that isFeatureFlagEnabled is indeed false when this code block is executed. What could be causing this behavior? Is there a fundamental aspect of Ember.js or HTML that I'm missing?

Are you sure that isFeatureFlagEnabled is a boolean? Because a string "false" is not actually false

Yes, it is boolean

The code provided contains no indication of why this would be the case. We are missing all the context around it, like, say, the actual object used when processing this template or the like. Without it, this can't be resolved. I'm willing to bet that the issue is not the template parser because if/else not working would make any template parser unusable, so the mistake is somewhere in code not provided.

let's be a little softer in our responses to folks learning <3

Could you post your actual code please rather than a simplified version? Unless you have found that the simplified version doesn't work it's of limited benefit to those trying to help you. It might be an idea to create a test component and see if your simplified version exhibits the same problem.

How are you testing for the presence of the tabIndex attribute? It won't be present in the HTML but the JavaScript property will still be there; however it should have a value of "-1"


What could be causing this behavior?

Either your if logic or your testing is incorrect.

Is there a fundamental aspect of Ember.js or HTML that I'm missing?

No. This is a a result of your code or an add-on.
